# Getting Syntax Error where none was before

Tags: python, sqlite, error-handling, syntax-error

I have this code snippet:

```
import sqlite3
import cld
import langid

languagedata = [] #list for the returned data from database
n = -1
connector = sqlite3.connect("GERMANY.db")
selecter = connector.cursor()
selecter.execute(''' SELECT title FROM DATAGERMANY''')
for row in selecter: #iterate through all the rows in db
    print (row)
    lan = langid.classify("{}".format(row)) #identify the language
    print (lan)
    connector.execute('''update DATAGERMANY set title_abbreviation_langid=? , title_reliability_langid=? where id_db == ? ''',(lan[-2], lan[-1])
 connector.commit() #save changes
 connector.close()
```

I run it like 100 times and it worked just fine. I added another `for loop` and then removed it again. So I should not have changed anything in the code. But now I get an `Invalid Syntax` error for `connector.commit()`.

How is that possible?!

[image: traceback]

NOTE: There is no more information on the error.

Comment: the traceback would be useful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what is a traceback? the idl highlights `connector` red

Comment: the full error code you received

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `Invalid Syntax` and then the word `connector` gets highlighted red. Not more

Comment: so when you run the code you get no proper traceback output?

Comment: Nope. Thats it. As I wrote. When I go into the IDLE Window the word `connector` is highlighted red. Thats it. Ill attach a screen

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added. There is a popup window it says `Invalid Syntax`. That cannot be captured

Comment: where are you running this from?

Comment: Python 3.3 IDLE on OS X 10.6

Comment: where  is `dbconnector`?

Comment: I mean the code you posted and your actual code is different, paste your actual code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  `db connector`? You mean the connector to the database? Sixth line the `connector` is created.
Changed it! After I added an extra loop, nested in the first for loop and wanted to tested that one and then the error occured. I removed the nested loop and since then the error occurs. The screen I posted was with the nested loop.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep. Just realised it. Sorry for the fuss. I copied the code into another IDLE window and renamed everything to see weather the error occurs there aswell. The screen was taken from the actual code where the error occured first time. Now it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren on this line:

```
connector.execute('''update DATAGERMANY set title_abbreviation_langid=? , title_reliability_langid=? where id_db == ? ''',(lan[-2], lan[-1])) # added paren here
```

I added a closing paren, your code should be ok now.

Comment: Cant believe it! Thank you so much! Weird that it goes to `connector` though

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: No worries, I had a sneaking suspicion that was the issue but I could not see your code in the screenshot, often the error can be in the line before where python shows the error in the traceback.

Comment: It must have happened when I removed the nested loop. Did not know that. I was staring at `connector` and tried to figure out what was wrong with it. I copied it like 10 times from above but still the error. Good to know that python goes every now and then one line above the actual error.